# Keycloak and spring security adapter: Company's proxy

Tags: spring-security, proxy, keycloak

I developed sso login with Keycloak and spring security adapter and all works fine.
But now I need to authenticate to my company's proxy all the requests to the Keycloak server, that stays out of my LAN.
I didn't find anything about this.
Please, may you give some suggestions?
Thanks

P.s. I am using Keycloak version 1.7.0-Final

Comment: The problem has been resolved

Comment: Can you provide the solution as an answer to your question for future reference?